# How can I get gridviews inside of multiple navigation tabs to refresh?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have an asp.net page with navigation tabs that display 2 different Gridviews when clicking between the tabs.  I want both Gridviews to be refreshed every 5 minutes but i'm having issues doing so.  The first Gridview which is in the first tab that loads refreshes fine but the other Gridview on the other tab isn't refreshing. Below is my code.

ASPX:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Inbound</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Outbound</a></li>
</ul>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

<div id="tabs-1">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">

<!--- Refresh Gridview every 5 minutes --------------------->
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="300000" ontick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>
<!---------------------------------------------------------->
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>  
 </asp:UpdatePanel> 
</div>

<div id="tabs-2">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">

<!--- Refresh Gridview every 5 minutes --------------------->
<asp:Timer ID="Timer2" runat="server" Interval="300000" ontick="Timer2_Tick"></asp:Timer>
<!---------------------------------------------------------->
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server"></asp:GridView>  
 </asp:UpdatePanel> 
</div>
```

C#:

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strQuery = "select * from Table1";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
        GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    protected void Timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strQuery2 = "select * from Table2";
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(strQuery2);
        GridView2.DataSource = GetData(cmd2);
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }
```